# TSQL Translation into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have SQL which I run against the on premises database. In the WHERE clause I am narrowing it down to year

```
WHERE YEAR(SRCSYS_ADD_DATE_TIME)=2020
```

and I get the results

In Snowflake work sheet I am using

```
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(SRCSYS_ADD_DATE_TIME))=2020
```

and I am getting this message

`Date '2020-05-28-20.42.09.724117' is not recognized'`

Please need help.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake's [automatic date-time parsing](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) isn't recognizing your period separated timestamp formatting.

You'll need to explicitly [specify a format to read the string](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#label-date-time-format-conversion) during conversion:

```sql
EXTRACT(
  YEAR FROM
  TO_DATE('2020-05-28-20.42.09.724117', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF')
) = 2020
```

Comment: You can also set the format at the session level: alter session set DATE_INPUT_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF';

Answer (score 0):

bkan.

The problem is the timestamp format. If you don't specify a timestamp format, Snowflake will try to autodetect. In this case it can't, so you'll have to specify the timestamp format:

```
select year(to_timestamp('2020-05-28-20.42.09.724117', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6'));
```

If you don't want to specify the timestamp format, your best option is using YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS.FFFFF (or some other precision of fractional seconds) like this:

```
select year('2020-05-28 20:42:09.724117'::timestamp);
```

The second option reformats the timestamp to the standard format, and the ::timestamp syntax casts it to a timestamp.